# Debian crashed, file system is read-only and cannot backup - How Do I find/mount a USB drive?

Tags: debian, filesystems, server-crashes, read-only

We have a Debian server (vm's) here at work and the server crashed after a power failure. I can only boot the system in maintenance mode, and the whole file system is set to read only. I can run fsck though maintenance mode, however I would like to get a backup of some files before I do. Problem: I cannot access the net since there is no network connectivity in maintenance mode, and for some reason I try to add a USB flash drive to the computer but I can't find it through the console.

Question: how to you find/mount a usb drive on Debian? I have tried several resources from the internet but nothing worked. 
Is there any other way I could get a backup of my files? I cannot start networking since the filesystem is set to read only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you plug the usb drive it will be detected automatically and you could then find its "device name" in the outuput of `dmesg` (look for /dev/sdX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start networking without a writable filesystem -- you just probably can't use the init scripts to do it (newer versions of Debian use a tmpfs for this, but I'm going to assume you're not using one of those).  Just use `ip` (or `ifconfig` if that's your bag) to give the interface an IP and bring it up:

```
ip addr add 192.0.2.69/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up
```

If you need to talk to a machine off your local subnet, you can add a default route, too:

```
ip route add default via 192.0.2.254 dev eth0
```

Mounting a USB drive on Debian is exactly the same as it is on every other Linux distribution:

```
mount /dev/sdXN /mnt
```

You might be hitting limitations due to `/etc/mtab` not being writable, which is cool, just give `mount` the `-n` option.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, after giving the commands you just mentioned, the network is still not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Diagnostic information, for starters.

Comment: It looks like I am half way through. I have used instructions from this website http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugbasicnet.html (thanks to your hint for manual configuration) but still there is something missing as there is networking but no connection to the outside world. I am probably missing this line as I am receiving an error * Tell your machine that a hub is ready for information with the command "route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth0. * What exactly does it do?

Comment: And what was the solution? The key here isn't just *asking* questions, it's *sharing the knowledge*.  From the look of things, you'd configured your network interface, but failed to set up routing by defining a default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the vm start from an image of any live distro.  I dont know if you have kvm, xen or virtualbox /vmwarem, etc.  But most would let you start from a cd. With that you can recover most your files, I would recommend rescuecd.
To your other question

```
how to you find/mount a usb drive on Debian?
```

With the commands

lsusb, dmesg
and with the command mount
mount -t vfat /dev/sdXY /mount/point/you/choose

You can even drop the -t vfat, most of the time linux will recognize what type of partition you are using.